# Strip down GNOME in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS visual to the very bare minimum and make it faster

Tags: gnome, 22.04, performance, window, wayland

Hello I'm on a notebook that is running a virtual machine with ubuntu 22 lts, but for various reasons (security one of them) I'm not using VM tools or 3D acceleration so the system is a bit laggy, mainly due system animations.

The desktop environment is **GNOME**, while I do know that I could use lubuntu I'm curious if instead I could manage with some settings to make GNOME faster.

I could also consider removing packages or pieces, my only need is firefox with addons.

Tried already disabling animation in accessibility panel but it doesn't speed the things so much.

I'm wondering if I can do the same tricks I used to do in Windows world with Windows XP, Windows Vista and 7 like

- switching to **from a rich style to a plain** Windows 2000 style interface
- set things like **MenuShowDelay** that is in windows the settings where when you roll on a menu they are displayed with an initial delay of 400ms to 0ms

Can I increase to the maximum the use of the ram and vram of the gpu and/or do other things to speedup GNOME to the maximum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlikely. A better bet is to install a gnome2 (like budgie or cinnamon). Less resources  for the theme than gnome3 but more than LXDE. "I  could also consider removing packages or pieces, my only need is firefox with addons." that will not speed things up. it will only limit usage of your system to the installed software. Disable/remove services is what will save power and speed up booting. General speed is unlikely you can improve unless you switch DE (ie. gnome3, lxde or xfce).

Comment: Development work on Ubuntu 22.04 ended two years ago. The version of Gnome is slightly older, so both are poor choices for testing improvements. Consider trying a newer release of Ubuntu, which comes with a newer version of Gnome. It's curious that you assume Ubuntu and Gnome are (deliberately) hobbled, to be freed by the tweak of a setting or two. Who would want that?

Comment: Well to me it seems that there are some hardcoded (or changeable) animations in menu showup and so on, if these can be changed the responsiveness of the os would improve. There's an addon for gnome called "Impatience" but didn't test yet, and not sure how trusted the gnome extensions are in terms of security.